# Optimal Linux Distro to Install to SD card to use as USB-Bootloader for PC?

Tags: linux, usb

(Copied from [andoid stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/optimal-linux-distro-to-install-to-sd-card-to-use-as-usb-bootloader-for-pc))

Many people install Linux-based distros on USB drives to use for, largely, basic PC troubleshooting. Has anyone tried installing such a thing on their Android phone's SD card? That way instead of carrying about both a USB drive and a phone, one could simply plug their phone in, boot the PC from USB, and set about performing whatever actions are necessary. Does anyone have any recommendations for particular flavors of Linux which are best suited to this task?

Comment: I just wonder, because Android is Linux already, why can't one use an Android phone to boot a PC and troubleshoot?

Comment: Android is, for the most part, Linux compiled for various ARM architectures, and so what's on your phone would not boot on a PC.  Besides, the USB slave mode does not expose the root filesystem which is necessary to boot.

Comment: Could you clarify that comment?  Are you saying that my goal here is unachievable?

Comment: I'm saying that @phunehehe's comment is unreasonable.  @maxschlepzig's answer seems likely to work, although it has absolutely nothing to do with the Linux running on the phone itself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess if your Android phone is able to act as an USB stick to the PC then every distribution installable on a normal USB stick will do it.

For troubleshooting stuff [GRML](http://grml.org/) is really great. They also have instructions how to install it on a USB stick (as a 'live-usb-stick').

Comment: Two more in addition to GRML: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php and http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/